# Placeholder text color doesn't work on submit type

Tags: css

I've followed [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css) about styling the text in placeholders but i still run into problems.

Regard the following code. For some reason, the background gradient is effective on both my input field and the submit button **but** the text color of the placeholder is only black in the former. The last remains gray looking like if it's disabled. Why is it so and what can be done about it?

```
div.login input[type=text],
div.login input[type=submit]{
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 0px 1px rgba(40, 40, 255, .6);
  background: #989898;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #cc66ee 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#cc66ee 100%);
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: #000000;
}

input:-moz-placeholder{
  color: #000000;
}
```

I tried it out on both Chrome and FF.

**Please do not reply that the issue is with me using single/double colon in the different cases (unless you've got a really heavy reason). It's apparently supposed to be that way since one refers to a pseudo class and the other to a pseudo element.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized **why** it is like that and **how** to resolve it.

WHY?

Because the text on the button isn't a placeholder, which i mistakingly believed. It's just a normal text.

HOW?

By using the mysterious style of "color".